# Can I add or change search tags in Unity's Dash

Tags: unity, unity-dash, tag

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and I use two languages English and Russian.

So i need to switch all the time to English to find and launch applications, for example Clementine.

Is it possible that I set somewhere Russian spelling for Clementine and it will work for search in Dash?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can change the name of an software(Without any programming). But in file names, you can use different languages. So, when you search them in your language, you will find them.

Comment: Yeah, I know.   I don't want to change software name, but I believe there is a way to add some tags.  I started to use "Create Launcher " app (available in Software center) - and I can do it there.